# SteelToe with Eureka server

Tags: .net, server, netflix-eureka, steeltoe

I am developing .net core application using steel toe. I have eureka installed on my server and I have updated my appSettings.json. Now when, I  run the application, it is just running and not being registered with remote server
Do we need to do something to get connected to remote eureka server from  the development machine?

Any help on this appreciated

Comment: Can you please include which version of Steeltoe and the code you're using to add service discovery to the application? It may also be relevant to include the appsettings you added

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to access a remote Eureka server is the right connection information and an open network path. If you've made sure the address and credentials are correct and that there are no network barriers, you should be able to see information in the logs from the Eureka client under the namespace `Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka`